# Guardar datos en un .txt

Tags: c++, txt, archivo, guardar

Adjunto parte final del código

```
switch(OPCION)
    {
    case 1:
        {
        Guardar.open("Registros.txt",ios::out); //Abrir el archivo, crea o reemplaza el archivo.
        system("cls");
        printf("Ingrese Nombre(s):\n"); scanf("\t %s",&NOMBRE);
        printf("Ingrese Apellido(s):\n"); scanf("\t %s",&APELLIDO);
        printf("Ingrese Edad:\n"); scanf("\t%i",&EDAD);
        printf("Ingrese DPI:\n"); scanf("\t%i",&DPI);
        printf("Ingrese No. de Telefono:\n"); scanf("\t%i",&TEL);
        fprintf Guardar("%s%s%i%i%i", NOMBRE, APELLIDO, EDAD, DPI, TEL);
        break;
        ofstream Temp;
        }
    }
    return 0;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uso.

La función fprintf forma parte de las librerías C adaptadas a C++ y reside en la cabecera , la firma de la función es la siguiente:

```
int fprintf( std::FILE* archivo, const char* formato, ... );
```

- El parámetro archivo debe ser un puntero a manejador de archivo (std::FILE*) el cuál se obtiene mediante la función fopen, no hay que olvidar cerrar el archivo con fclose.
- El parámetro formato es una cadena de texto con diferentes especificadores de formato.
- Los parámetros en ... serán una lista separada por comas de los datos que deben coincidir con los especificadores de formato.

Por lo tanto, el uso que deberías darle a fprintf debería ser:

```
archivo = std::fopen("mi_archivo.txt", "w");


std::fprintf(archivo, "%s%d%d", cliente, apartamento, npiso);
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!